# SQL issue SELECT statement

Tags: sql, select

I'm not the best in SQL. My problem is that my sql sequence doesn't take my ON Plant.id =1 statement to account.
Heres a part of the database: [db_part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uPr5.png)

```
    SELECT 
    Censor_Data_Greenhouse.value AS gVal, 
    Censor_Data_Greenhouse.time_date AS gClock, 
    Data_Type_Greenhouse.name AS gDatatype
    FROM Censor_Data_Greenhouse 
    JOIN Data_Type_Greenhouse 
    ON Censor_Data_Greenhouse.data_type = Data_Type_Greenhouse.id
    LEFT JOIN Plant
    ON (Plant.greenhouse=greenhouse.id
    AND Plant.id = 1)
    ORDER BY gClock DESC
```

Comment: You're not defining the relationship between 'Plant' and the other tables,  I'm not sure what you expect to happen but you're effectively doing a cartesian join at this point.

Comment: @JeffUK do I need to change my database or just the sql sequence?

Comment: I don't know what you want the query to do.. so I can't say!   You probably want to add plant.greenhouse=Censor_Data_Greenhouse.greenhouse in there somewhere

Comment: I want to get what I selected when the value of Plant.id, which is on a completely different table as you can see in the picture, equals to one. I tried adding the plant.greenhouse=greenhouse.id, I'm just not sure where and how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Insted of joining Plant out of the blue. I first joined greenhouse on the condition that it matched with the results. Then I could join the plant now that the greenhouse.id was 'declared'.

Thanks.